# Magento 2 Cart get empty on page referesh only in Mozila firefox

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.7, magento-2.1.9

I am using magento 2.1.7 version. I have upgraded it to 2.1.9 after upgradation it is working fine on google chrome, but on Firefox cart get empty on refresh page or apply coupon code it also get empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out is is due to session regeneration code in file `vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php` as below

```
$oldSessionId = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
$newSessionId = session_id();
session_id($oldSessionId);
session_destroy();

$oldSession = $_SESSION;
session_id($newSessionId);
session_start();
$_SESSION = $oldSession;
```

As of now temporary solution replace above code with below code

```
session_regenerate_id(false);
```

Comment: Have you found a more robust solution that this or have any further insight into the cause ? This issue occurred on a site and I had to roll back. I'm unable to recreate it locally.

Comment: I didn't found any solution. I have also done roll back

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work around for this this doesn't require you to make a modification to Magento's code base.

If you change your sessions storage to be DB rather than Files I can no longer recreate the issue.

Change : 
app/etc/env.php

```
...
'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
...
```

to

```
...
'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'db',
  ),
...
```

Obviously there are inherent downsides here i.e. writing sessions to the DB can cause the database to bloat, so wouldn't be ideal if you are working with a large catalog.